# How to convert a dictionary into a flat list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Given a Python `dict` like:

```
{
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}
```

What's an easy way to create a flat list with keys and values in-line? E.g.:

```
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]
```

Comment: `(list(itertools.chain(*sorted(d.iteritems()))))`

Comment: `your_list = list(eval(your_dict.__str__().replace(':',',')))` , or use a regex to replace `':'` to `','`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are using Python 2.7, I would recommend using `dict.iteritems` or `dict.viewitems` and list comprehension, like this

```
>>> [item for pair in d.iteritems() for item in pair]
['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2]
>>> [item for pair in d.viewitems() for item in pair]
['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2]
```

`dict.iteritems` or `dict.viewitems` is better than `dict.items` because, they don't create a list of key-value pairs.

If you are wondering how you can write portable code which would be efficient in Python 3.x as well, then you just iterate the keys like this

```
>>> [item for k in d for item in (k, d[k])]
['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
In [39]: d = {                                   
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}

In [40]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.items()))
Out[40]: ['b', 2, 'a', 1, 'c', 3]
```

Note that dicts are unordered, which means that the order in which you enter keys is not always the order in which they are stored. If you want to preserve order, you might be looking for an [ordereddict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: remarkably, It is not much slower than `[item for pair in d.items() for item in pair]`: `1.05` µs vs. `681` ns.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I think I'm starting my secret love affair with functional programming. So secret, that even I didn't know about it

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: would the time difference be more pronounced with a larger dict?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> sum(d.items(), tuple())
('a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2)
```

Comment: Clever; `list(sum(d.items(), tuple()))` achieves the desired result.

Comment: @blah238 I wouldn't use it if you have a big dictionary, though, as it's somewhat slow compared to the other methods. Some might argue that it's unpythonic, but I like its functional flavor.

Comment: this is incredibly inefficient, try `d = {k:k for k in range(100000)}` and go have a cup of tea.

Comment: yes but itertools or a  list comp can do it in roughly `15ms`, I had to ctrl-d trying to time yours or my cpu was going to explode. I love functional programming but this is just wrong!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, and you have to import itertools to use `chain`, and the list comprehension is rather incomprehensible. If your `dict` is big, then yeah, this is "wrong". But if you're playing around in the interpreter and you have a `dict` with only a few elements, you'd have a hard time convincing me that this solution is "wrong". There's a time and a place.

Comment: almost every question on SO is based on toy examples, you try to answer with an efficient solution that will scale, this really is a terrible solution. also if the list comp is *rather incomprehensible* then I don't know what to call yours.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I disagree that this solution is terrible -- there are many instances where I care not about scalability, but about readability, or even keystrokes. You're free to downvote and move on. As long as the reader is aware of the potential problems of this solution, then I don't see an issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
res_list = []
for k, v in d:
    res_list.append(k).append(v)
```