# Turn dictionary into one long list of strings?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
fruits_dict = {"apple":"red", "banana":"yellow", "kiwi":"green"}
```

And I want the result to be all the keys and values combined into one list:

```
fruits_list = ["apple", "red", "banana", "yellow", "kiwi", "green"]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way is to iterate over all the keys, and for each key append the key itself, and the associated value, to the list, or to use one of the solutions shown here: [How to convert a dictionary into a flat list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612626/how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-flat-list)

Comment: `fruits_list = list(eval(fruits_dict.__str__().replace(':',',')))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
new_iter = chain.from_iterable(fruits_dict.items())
```

That will make an iterator, if you need a list:

```
>>> [ x for x in new_iter ]
[ 'apple', 'red', 'banana', 'yellow', 'kiwi', 'green' ]
```

And of course, if you want for example a comma-separated string:

```
', '.join(new_iter)
```

You should definitely NOT accomplish this with string processing as might be tempting unless you can fully reason, validate, or sanitize the strings in your dictionary. One might "blah" at this as pedantic - but this is exactly how bugs that hackers take advantage of end up in software.

`itertools.chain` and friends is the short and correct answer to your question using the python standard library and best practices. In general, `itertools` is super useful for iterator wrangling like this! You might want to look at the docs for that module, it's got a lot of cool functions especially for working with permutations etc.

Comment: ahhh so rusty, forgot .items() - thanks made edit

Comment: hackers trying to submit strings that break your code? always safer to assume your input could be anything unless you sanitize, validate, or can otherwise reason that you will never get a particular input. That makes this answer correct in a larger variety of situations.